# PHP getting html between <ul> tags

Tags: php, html

Okay, so I have a javascript script that gets 2 values, and inserts them into each of the corrosponding `<Ul>` tags shown below in HTML.

```
    <h4>Value 1:</h4>
    <ul></ul>
    <h4>Value 2:</h4>
    <ul></ul>
```

The javascript is able to display the 2 values on the HTML page by inserting the first value into the first set of `<ul>` tags and the 2nd value into the 2nd set of `<ul>` tags. SO on the webpage it is displayed, but for various reasons, I need those values to be saved as PHP strings. I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
    <form method="POST">
        <h4>Value 1</h4>
        <ul id="value1"></ul>
        <h4>Value 2</h4>
        <ul id="value2"></ul>
    </form>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['value1'])) {
    $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
}
?>
```

The above didn't work, and this was confusing for me as I am aware that PHP is server side and javascript is client side, and the PHP on a page loads first. However, there has to be some way to do a !empty statement for the `<ul>` tags that would save their contents as a PHP variable as soon as they became not empty. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use the GET method or POST method for the form in order to get it to work.

Anyways, any ideas / help would greatly be appreciated, and FYI, the reason I need them saved as PHP strings / variables is to then save them as session variables and transfer them to the next page, I also wanted to set up some file, say perhaps file.txt, that logs the output of what is between the 2 `<ul>` tags for each person that visits the site. Basically, it is crucial to save what is between the `<ul>` tags as a PHP variable / string.

EDIT: It would be convienent to use `<input>` instead of `<ul>`, but I cannot do that becuase my javascript recognizes the `<ul>` tags, both of them, and inserts a long list of data into them, and that process is automatic, there is no form submission.

EDIT 2: When posting this, I was entering `<ul>` raw, without doing insert code, and this made it invisible in the actual post, which would have made it confusing to read. I've fixed it.

Comment: You may try to post them via ajax to avoid some field restrictions.

Comment: Try to change your question title. The title make one understand that there a string between the `ul` and you need to extract it.

Answer (score 1):

Via ajax:

**js**

```
        var value1 = $('#value1').val();
        var value2 = $('#value2').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                value1:value1,
                value2:value2
            },
            success: function(){
                alert('Ok');
            }
        });
```

**php**

```
$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2'];

$file = 'yourFile.txt';
$fileContent = file_get_contents($file);
$fileContent .= $value1 . '\n';
$fileContent .= $value2 . '\n';
file_put_contents($file, $fileContent);
```

Comment: How could I automatically save those 2 values to a text document?

Comment: It's simple. (updated php code) | some useful info http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

It need to be `<input>` if you want PHP recognize it. Try adding hidden input

```
 <form method="POST">
        <h4><input type="hidden" value="Value 1"/>Value 1</h4>
       ...
    </form>
```